# What is the preferred way to byte swap values in Rust?

Tags: rust

I see that before Rust 1.0, there used to be functions like `std::mem::from_be16` as well as `core::mem::from_be16`. The documentation for both modules claims that all of the byte swapping routines are deprecated, and indeed they were removed for Rust 1.0.

Is there anything built into Rust which can do the swap and is not deprecated or would I have to implement my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use methods like [`i32::from_be`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.from_be).

For future reference if you run code with deprecated functions the recommended replacement should be shown by the compiler or alternatively view the source code of the function which should have something like this

```
#[deprecated = "use `i32::from_be` instead"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice if this info was also in the documentation. I was doing some research but didn't think it would be documented solely in the source.

Comment: If you hover over the “deprecated” marker, you’ll observe it has title text, the deprecation message. (No, this is not sufficient.)

Comment: So it does. While its not exactly apparent it certainly is better than the data not being there.

Answer (score 3):

Methods like [`u16::swap_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.swap_bytes) sound more relevant to the wording of the question.